# Julia exits when running code with MATLAB.jl

Tags: julia

When trying to execute any commands from MATLAB.jl in julia, the matlab command window opens, and Julia immediately exits with no errors, warnings, or messages. Has anyone else encountered this before? I'm working on translating some MATLAB code to julia and using MATLAB.jl to check that the sparse matrices are the same for both pieces of code.

I'm on a Windows computer and have tried following the instructions on the MATLAB.jl github repo. I've also tried adding Matlab to path and executing the code from the Julia REPL, but keep encountering the same problem.

I can get `mxarray` executes, however, trying it seems like anything which requires a matlab session causes julia to quit, e.g. `mxcall`, `md""`, and `MSession`.

[image]

Comment: You're going to need to give a lot more info here to get good help. Does it error? Is there a message? Is there a stack trace?

Comment: @OscarSmith Thanks for your advice, I've tried to add more detail to the post, however I haven't got much more info to share. Julia closes without throwing any errors, warnings or messages so I can't run a stack trace. Some functions seem to work, however it seems like the issue arises when julia tries to call the matlab session.

Comment: that makes absolutely no sense. if something is quitting your repl, it really should be printing something.

Comment: @OscarSmith, I agree that it does not make any sense. Although it may not be very useful, i've attached a screenshot of the REPL from starting julia to the point where it exits without a warning.

Comment: Can you run Matlab from the ; prompt in the Julia REPL? If not I wonder if the installation cannot start Matlab when called.

Comment: @Bill Just tried running `; MATLAB` in the REPL and it was able to open up matlab without any issues. The problem seems to still persist when calling any matlab code from MATLAB.jl though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to solve the problem by opening julia through the command prompt as an administrator and running `] build MATLAB` and `] test MATLAB`. If the terminal was not opened as administrator, it would build, however, during the testing it would return `exit error: 3765269347`, which seems to be a windows-specific internal process error.

After this has been done, MATLAB.jl seems to work even when it is not opened directly with admin rights.